# trying to call method I'm getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a game on android, text quest.

I have process called "work" what it does is giving player chance to choose work place and how much time he wants to work, then process this information.

Below is code of two methods "**checkWorkPlaces()**" that checks if there are places to work in the city player are in, and then it calls "**chooseWorkPlace()**" method, that gives player chance to choose where he wants to work.

- *tvInfo* - **TextView**, I show all information on it.
- *player* - object of my custom class **Player**, that has such property as **location** of custom class **Place**, that has property **name** and *workPlaces* - array that contains work places of class **WorkPlace**, every one of those has **definition** and **name** property.
- *answerContainer* - just **ArrayList** that I use to pass some information between methods.
- *btnMainGame* - actually just a **Button**, that I use to save user information
- *hideButtons()* - hides some buttons on screen [not important for my question]

  ```
  protected void checkWorkPlaces() {

  answerContainer.clear();

  if (player.location.workPlaces.length > 0) {

      tvInfo.setText("In " + player.location.name + " there are a few places to work:");

      for (WorkPlace workPlace : player.location.workPlaces) {
          tvInfo.append("\n" + workPlace.defenition);
      }
      tvInfo.append("Where do you want to work?");

      chooseWorkPlace();


  } else {
      tvInfo.setText("There is nowhere to work in " + player.location.name);
  }

  }


  protected void chooseWorkPlace() {

  hideButtons();

  btnMainGame.setText(getString(R.string.save));
  btnMainGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          if (etInput.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              chooseWorkPlace();

          } else {
              answerContainer.add(etInput.getText().toString().toLowerCase());

          }
      }
  });

  String choice = answerContainer.get(0).toString().toLowerCase();
  answerContainer.clear();

  if (!Objects.equals(choice, "back")) {

      for (WorkPlace workPlace : player.location.workPlaces) {

          if (Objects.equals(workPlace.name.toLowerCase(), choice)) {

              answerContainer.add(workPlace);
              return;
          }
      }

      tvInfo.append("\n\nThere is no such work place as: " + choice + ", try again");
      chooseWorkPlace();

  }

  }
  ```

So, the problem is, that when program starts to call **chooseWorkPlace()** method it stops the program with java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.griseostrigiformes.textwarrior, PID: 4916
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.example.griseostrigiformes.textwarrior.MainSystem.MainActivity.chooseWorkPlace(MainActivity.java:521)
    at com.example.griseostrigiformes.textwarrior.MainSystem.MainActivity.checkWorkPlaces(MainActivity.java:492)
    at com.example.griseostrigiformes.textwarrior.MainSystem.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:124)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `answerContainer` is empty.

Comment: Debug the code, you will get the error line number

Comment: @AnkitDemonstrate i debugged my code is says, that problem is in line that calls out chooseWorkPlace()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems to be giving you the error,

```
String choice = answerContainer.get(0).toString().toLowerCase();
```

May be you should first check the size of `answerContainer` before getting element at zero index? OR you should debug why `answerContainer` is empty.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, just I started to do this game on console and it worked perfectly all the time.